# Checking external hardware through serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication

In my code, I'm setting the following values:

```
public SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();
comPort.PortName = portName;
```

The `PortName` can be COM17, for example.

Now if I've add two devices through my GUI, both on COM17, one will eventually throw an exception (Access to COM17 denied). Now I'd like to check which device is hooked on that COM-port so if my application recognises it, it can send commands through the port, or if it's not recognized, it'll disable the option in my GUI.

So, is there a way to get unique information from the COM-port which I can save in my database when it's being installed?

EDIT: To clarify, if the wrong device is hooked to that COM port (other than when I installed), I get an error. I catch that error so I know it's not the right one. But I'd rather like to know which device that might be. Say I've got 2 drivers DLL's included, 2 different devices, and somebody switched them up. Then my application could check and see the correct names, and therefore conclude it's only a matter of changing the COM-ports of the installed objects, instead of just throwing an error and saying the user has to reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to depend on your hardware. If the devices attached will give a predictable and consistent response to a particular signal message, then you can use that to identify them. I do the same thing to figure out which COM port a piece of proprietary hardware is attached to. I iterate through all the COM ports and send a message that I know will give a particular response from the hardware. Which ever port gives me the expected result is the one with the hardware.

Comment: I thought of this one as well. Still, if I have 10+ hardware pieces attached of which 7 are the same type, it gets harder. Is there a possibility to get the Hardware ID or something else that is unique?

Comment: @Joetjah: Only if the hardware itself supports it. If the hardware can send a message back with a serial number or similar, then yeah. If not, no. I have the same problem. Our hardware doesn't have a function that'll give me a serial number, but luckily nobody ever connects more than one at a time.

Comment: Allright, that seems reasonable enough. Too bad, it'd make my life a lot easy at the moment. Thank you for the information.